# Android Java Fragment Data/Layout Transfer

Tags: java, android

Keep getting no view found when calling dialog fragment from another fragment. I am trying to send image location to the dialog fragment to display.

Originating Fragment

```
mLEFTBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Log.d("gogo", "left photo");

                DialogFragment fm = new DialogFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("stringUri",stringUri);
                //contains the location to be sent and re opened.
                fm.setArguments(bundle);
                fm.show(getChildFragmentManager(), stringUri);


            }
        });
```

Ending Fragment

```
public class PhotoLeft extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "PhotoLeft";
    public static ImageView FragImageView;
    private TextView mActionOK, mActionCancel;
    private File mPhotoFile;
    public static Bitmap bmLarger;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        Log.d("gogo","inphoto1");
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String stringUri = bundle.getString("stringUri");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(stringUri);
        FragImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d("gogo","inphoto");


        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see you have define you xml or view in dialog fragment.Please add it to render view of your dialog

```
public class PhotoLeft extends DialogFragment{
       
    
    
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_dialog, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);
    
            // Retrieve layout elements
            ImageView FragImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imaageview);
    
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            String stringUri = bundle.getString("stringUri");

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(stringUri);
            FragImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



            // Build dialog
            Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity());
            builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            builder.setContentView(view);
            return builder;
        }
    }
```